# Django : Cannot resolve the URLs pattern : Always Index page content is displayed

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am learning Django. I build an app in which I am setting up the URL patterns but in all cases it's displaying the data for the index page.

appTwo urls.py File :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.users, name='users'),
    url(r'^$', views.help, name='help'),
]
```

MyProject urls.py file :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/', include('appTwo.urls')),
    url(r'^help/', include('appTwo.urls')),
]
```

If I call /users or /help, the browser display the data for index file only.

Is there something with a regex that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are `appTwo.urls` the same as `MyApp/urls.py`? Also, which Django version are you using?

Comment: Yes they are same !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting your `urlpatterns` in a wrong way. First of all, in you project's `urls.py` file you are saying that if a request is sent to `/users` or `/help`, then Django should look into your `appTwo.urls`. When Django gets there, it finds that the `urlpatters` are set so that everything that's empty after any of the aforementioned urls must be handled by the `views.index`, `views.users` and `views.help`. But as `views.index` is the first one in the list, then all the request end up being handled by that view.

By the way, if you're using Django >= 2.0 you no longer need to use the `url()` function, but the `path()` one instead, for which you can declare the paths as simple strings rather than regular expressions.

You should have something as follows:

**MyProject/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('appTwo.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**MyApp/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('users/', views.users, name='users'),
    path('help/', views.help, name='help'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks !! With path, I was able to solve the issue !!

Answer (score 0):

when django reaches here (in your apps url) while resolving the urls, see all three urls have empty regex as first param (so the first one will be selected), And as you see its index then you always show index page. You need to differentiate the urls. Something like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
                      url(r'^users/$', views.users, name='users'),
                      url(r'^help/$', views.help, name='help'),
                      url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
                   ]
```

I think you also cant write url index with empty regex at top of other urls, otherwise it will always be selected.